# Mains circuit phase balancing relay?

Tags: hardware, power-consumption, ac-power, power-sources

I am looking for a device, like a special relay that would allow me to dynamically switch/move some of my home appliances between the 3 phases that I have on my mains circuit. Is this possible?

The goal is to maximize the self-consumed solar energy. My panels are connected to L1, and if there is surplus solar energy, I want to connect my washer or my dishwasher to L1. However, when there is less sun and we're using more energy, I want to connect them to L2 or L3 to avoid overload on L1.

Is there a device, like a smart relay for this?

Comment: You can use a DPDT switch to manually switch between L1 and L2. There are high current switches like that available. If you want, there are also high current DPDT contactors and maybe you can automate depending on solar intensity and time of day. But make sure that you check the building codes, insurance terms etc and the warranty/lease terms of the solar power system. They may require a qualified electrician to do all the work.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. What about the appliances? Will I harm them if I happen to switch the DPDT relay while they are working?